# Return FirstName from model to a label in View

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to render the FirstName entered by the user as a label in the View. I have tried...

```
@Html.DisplayFor(c => c.FirstName)
@Html.LabelFor(c => c.FirstName)
@Html.DisplayNameFor(c => c.FirstName)
```

What is the best way? Seems simple, I am obviously missing something? Using the second one, I am getting the variable name, not the value.

Controller Code:

```
namespace TestProject.Controllers
{
    public class ContactsController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            Contact contact = new Contact();

            return View(contact);
        }
    }
}
```

View Code:

```
@model TestProject.Models.Contact

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "ContactSuccess";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}


<h2>Contact Has Been Successfully Added</h2>
<div class="imgContainer">
<img src="~/Content/Images/checkmark" />
</div>

@model.FirstName
```

Model Code:

```
namespace TestProject.Models
{
    public class Contact 
    {
        [Required]
        [DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false)]
        [StringLength(20, MinimumLength = 2, ErrorMessage = "Enter A Valid First Name")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Enter A Valid Last Name")]
        [DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false)]
        [StringLength(20, MinimumLength = 2)]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Enter A Valid Home Phone Number including area code")]
        [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
        public string PhoneHome { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Enter A Valid Cell Phone Number")]
        [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
        public string PhoneCell { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Enter A Valid Email Address")]
        [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Enter A Valid Street Address")]
        [DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false)]
        [StringLength(120, MinimumLength = 4)]
        public string Address { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Enter A Valid City Name")]
        [DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false)]
        [StringLength(30, MinimumLength = 2)]
        public string City { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Enter A Valid State Abbreviation")]
        [DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false)]
        [StringLength(20, MinimumLength = 2)]
        public string State { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Enter A Valid 5 Digit Zip Code")]
        [DataType(DataType.PostalCode)]
        public string ZipCode { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show more code from your Action, View, and ViewModel/Model to explain what you are having trouble with? This should work.

Comment: My error, copied the wrong line, but I have tried that. It returns the variable name.

Comment: Just do `@model.FirstName` to render the contents of the field into the view.

Comment: @CraigW. - Tried that too and it now fails to load with the error, Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Are you actually passing a model to your view? Show your code from the controller action.

Comment: @CraigW. - Added code. Also, I added an image to the view after I originally posted and it dosen't render either?

Comment: In your GET action for the view, which initially displays the page, you are not assigning a value to the FirstName property, you are simply returning a blank model to the page. That is why you are receiving the error. You can add a conditional to check if FirstName is null before displaying, but I think the real question is what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Foo)
```

Outputs either the rendered result of an appropriate display template, or the value of the property as a string, if no appropriate template exists. Generates no HTML on its own, though the display template may contain HTML that will be rendered to the page.

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Foo)
```

Generates a `<label>` tag with the `for` attribute set to the HTML id that would be generated for the property and with contents the same as what you would get from `Html.DisplayNameFor`.

```
@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Foo)
```

Returns either the display name for the property (i.e. assuming your property had the attribute `[Display(Name = "My Awesome Foo")]` attached to it, "My Awesome Foo" would be output), or the name of the property, "Foo".

-

So assuming you want something like `<label>First Name</label>`, then you'd want `Html.LabelFor`. If you're talking about having something like `<label>Bob</label>`. There's no helper for that. You would have to literally just use:

```
<label>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.FirstName)</label>
```

Or simpler, just:

```
<label>@Model.FirstName</label>
```

The only reason to use `Html.DisplayFor` is when there's some sort of formatting you want applied, such as for a `DateTime` property, or you want a default or custom display template to be utilized. For `string` types, there is no default display template, so the result of `Html.DisplayFor` would be the same as outputting the property directly, unless you've created a custom template.